# how inject dependency in to another file (Angular js 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm writing tests now, and I want to create file with all functions I need,
( see screenshot 1)
[image: Screen shot 1]
and I want to inject this functions to all tests that I need ( you see example on screenshot 2)
[image: Screenshot 2]
how can I do this ? or some another solution to write DRY code

Comment: [**Answer for this issue**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)

Answer (score 0):

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp')
       .factory('MyFactory', MyFactory);

function MyFactory(){

   function myFun(){
      return 'hello world';
   }

   return {
      myFun : myFun
   }

}
```

Other Module, lets say **Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['MyFactory', '$scope'];

function MyController(MyFactory, $scope){

  . . .

  $scope.callSomething = function(){
    MyFactory.myFun().then( function(response){
     console.log(response);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: The main problem here that I don't need any Controller module or service where  I can add dependency,
I just need to set the function from  .factory to my other files (tests)
smt like in the Screenshot 2

Answer (score 0):

Will use [**this**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) solution
You can dive deeper in this question by the URL,